# Move ApplicationInsightsResourceId and ApplicationInsightsAnnotationResourceId from csproj to appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

Using Visual Studio 2019 I added Application Telemetry to a Web App project as per Step 1 from this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net). This created two entries in the csproj file below the target framework as below.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/abc</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
  <ApplicationInsightsAnnotationResourceId>/subscriptions/def</ApplicationInsightsAnnotationResourceId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

How do I move these to the appsettings.json file? Reason I need to do this I wish to use a different resource/subscription per environment for dev and production.

Comment: Just a FYI, as per ms document, you should create application insights as per dev / product environments, do not use one for the 2 environments.

Comment: Yes Ivan that's what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Though You can utilize a single resource, and use custom dimensions to tag the data source but it is always recommended to engender multiple Application Insights resources to split telemetry for different environments.

It comes with a lot of benefit ,like:

- Troubleshooting is pretty easy foe each environment
- You can have better disunion of telemetry, alerts, work items configuration, sanctions
- You get spread limit such as web count, can perform cross queries on multiple resources

For complete reference , you can check [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-application-insights-best-practices/) link from [Pam](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/author/pamlahoudhotmail-com/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to use one resource per environment, exactly. However the question is that the csproj is preventing that. The csproj has ApplicationInsightsResourceId and ApplicationInsightsAnnotationResourceId whereas for multiple environments these need to be in the application.json file.

Comment: Was OP's request ever figured out? I agree. The tags in the csproj file need to move to appsettings.json.